# jquery function access local javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-variables

New to jQuery and having simple yet confusing problem. ha2.

I am writing this normal javascript function with jQuery function reading xml file. How do I assigned value to the prodPrice variable declared on the top? the script keep returning 0 value, but if I alert the value within the jQuery function, I managed to get the value that I wanted.

Thank you guys.

```
function getPrice(valprodID)
{
    var prodPrice=0;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "products.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(xml)
        {
            jQuery(xml).find('prod').each(function(){
                var prodID = jQuery(this).find('prodID').text();
                if(prodID == valprodID)
                {
                    prodPrice = jQuery(this).find('prodPrice').text(); 
                    return false;
                }
            });                
        }
    })

    return prodPrice;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do asynchronous as reported by @xdazz, as @zerkms indicated with Deferred, or anonymous functions:

```
function getPrice(valprodID, fn)
{
    var prodPrice=0;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "products.xml",
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(xml)
        {
            jQuery(xml).find('prod').each(function(){
                var prodID = jQuery(this).find('prodID').text();
                if(prodID == valprodID)
                {
                    prodPrice = jQuery(this).find('prodPrice').text(); 
                    fn(prodPrice);
                }
            });                
        }
    })

}

getPrice(1, function(prodPrice) {

   /* your code */

})
```

Comment: yes it works. I can call the function getPrice. As with @zerkms example, the browser keep popping up undefined getPrice function. What is the difference between this two examples?

Comment: the example of "@zerkms" uses Deferred that was implemented in version 1.5 (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). my example is more common, use an anonymous function to then call the function "getPrice". you have to know that both are asynchronous because you use $.ajax asynchronously

Comment: @PapaShop in the example that happens to you "zerkms" is used the method "pipe" which is from the version 1.6 (http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/). you have to see what version of jQuery are using. You can use it without method "pipe", here is an example based on the code of "zerkms": http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/9MgsX/4/

Answer (score 2):

That's because `$.ajax` is performed asynchronously.

And it is a great chance for you to learn how to work with `$.Deferred`

```
function getPrice(valprodID)
{
    var prodPrice=0;

    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "products.xml",
        dataType : "xml"
    }).pipe(function(xml)
        {
            jQuery(xml).find('prod').each(function(){
                var prodID = jQuery(this).find('prodID').text();
                if(prodID == valprodID)
                {
                    return jQuery(this).find('prodPrice').text(); 
                }
            });                
        });
}
```

Now you call your `getPrice()` function in this way:

```
getPrice(someid).done(function(prodPrice) {
    // do what you need with prodPrice 
});
```

Here is an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/9MgsX/1/

Comment: fantastic! But why did you leave the `var prodPrice=0` statement in `getPrice()`?

Comment: @Ryan Fernandes: actually I couldn't understand what it is for :-S So get some generic answer PS: also added an example

Comment: @Ryan Fernandes: if you liked the promises I'd suggested you to look at this article http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/ It is amazing

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `async` option to `false`, or you should do your work in the callback function.